# Replace a table with other table on a common reference column in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

table 1:

[image: tABLE 1]

Table 2:

[image: Table 2]

Output File:

[image: Output image]

Here, I have table 1 which need to be replaced with table 2 based on 'ref' columns. Please help to resolve this problem. Merge, join is not helpful in this situation. I don't want to join table instead I need to replace the columns based on 'Ref' column in table 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do with `replace`:

```
table2 = table2.set_index('Ref')
for i in range(table1.shape[1]):
    table1.iloc[:,i] = table1.iloc[:,i].replace(table2.iloc[:,i])
```